# SoapUI basic authentication to c# code

Tags: web-services, authorization, soapui

I have problem with web service I want to connect to.
In soapUI i used basic authentication with username and password (domain empty), and changed WSS-Password Type to PasswordText and I could without a problem connect to web service. But when I try to connect using c# code:

```
WebService service = new WebService();
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
service.SomeMethod();
```

It returns "Forbidden" error.